# Updating openssl: openssl API level support

Tags: c, linux, api, openssl, libcrypto

I am trying to update from openssl 1.0.2 to something recent (like 3.0.1). The problem is that I have a huge amount of code and 3rd party libraries that depend on the older version of API and this becomes a kind of task with unrealistic estimates.
I found that openssl `configure` script has a great thing called API level that is intended to build the OpenSSL libraries to support the API for the specified version, however, I don't see any effect of that option.

Here is how I am using it:

```
$ ./Configure --api=1.0.2 --release --prefix=/opt/openssl
$ make -j
$ make install
```

and after that I am trying to use the build in `/opt/openssl`, but the code I was successfully building with openssl 1.0.2 fails to compile now.

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
$ g++ test.cpp -lcrypto -I/opt/openssl/include/ -L/opt/openssl/lib64/
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:16: error: aggregate ‘EVP_MD_CTX context’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    5 |     EVP_MD_CTX context;
      |                ^~~~~~~
```

Do I misunderstand something? What do I miss here?

Comment: Yes, you missed something. `EVP_MD_CTX` is an abstract struct declaration. It is (more or less) `struct EVP_MD_CTX;` - and that's *it*. If you find yourself declaring a concrete `EVP_MD_CTX` you're doing it wrong. All of the usage and manage of that artifact type is done via pointer mechanics and indirection (see `EVP_MD_CTX_new()` for example).

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand that, but the same code works in 1.0.2. The type was complete before, isn't that part of API?

Comment: Not according to the docs I've read. the entirety of the EVP digest API utilizes it strictly by address; not a concrete object, at least since I started using it in 1.0.1, through 1.0.2, 1.1.1, and now 3.0. It wouldn't be the first time such a bite has been felt. I had a similar experience when ripping apart DSA keys via dereference of the DSA struct in 1.0.2 (which is no longer possible in 1.1.1 and 3.0, but APIs are provided in all versions to accomplish the same goal, and had I been using them in the first place the port would have been transparent).

Comment: @WhozCraig another example is `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup` which is available in 1.0.2 but fails to compile in 3.0.1. What is the proper way of handling all this stuff? I have 3rd parties that refer to are trying to link these functions and I am not quite sure all those 3rd parties are supporting openssl 3.0.1 API.

Comment: Wow. still here. Anyway, the differences to the 3.0 API from prior versions is mentioned on the [openssl 3.0 wiki here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Upgrading_to_OpenSSL_3.0_from_OpenSSL_1.1.1). There, you'll see they specifically call out the removal of what *were* concrete types in prior versions, and in fact specifically mentions the message digest context as their example. I only remembered breezing across that a while ago because I saw it and knew I wouldn't fall prey since I used the `_new()` api vernacular from inception.

Answer (score 0):

From 3.0 API, The EVP_MD_CTX  struct is hidden from user. It is just forward declared in the SSL header files
/usr/include/openssl/types.h:105:typedef struct evp_md_ctx_st EVP_MD_CTX;

One needs to use `EVP_MD_CTX_create/new` in place of earlier usage of variable declaration
`EVP_MD_CTX  mdc` ;

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
   ...
   EVP_MD_CTX *mdc ; 

//(Even though struct is anonymous pointer to  anonymous
// struct can always be handled by compiler)

   mdc = EVP_MD_CTX_new() ; 

   EVP_MD_CTX_init(mdc);
   ...
   EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(mdc);
   EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdc) ;
```